# C++ development on Android on a Linux VM?

Tags: android, c++, c++11, google-play, virtual-machine

What is the best option today to do C++ software development **on** an Android platform? I need C++11, Boost, SQLite, vi/Emacs/whatever, ... and Android is the development platform, not necessarily the target.

Are the development tools on Google Play complete? Do they allow to develop a full scale application?

Are there any advantages in using a Linux VM on Android for this purpose?

Comment: Have you heard of AIDE - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en although I'm not sure if it would suit your need. Android is still more of a target platform than a full stack developer friendly platform.

Comment: I do toy development using c4droid.  What kind of high-powered android box are we talking about?  Might it be easier to develop in the cloud?  Like, rent a unix box and just putty in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use NDK with your android app development to embed a C++ code, which will improve the performance considering you are doing much complicated task and if you need native language like C++. But now android runtime [ART/Dalvik] is much better and all the apps are targeted to run on it. You can do a lot of work only in java itself.
And there is no VM available yet. So best way to go with this is use NDK.